# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 for 32 bit

Tags: 16.04, downloads, 32-bit

What is the best link to use to download Ubuntu 16.04 for a 32 bit desktop machine? I used the one on: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/   ( 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image) but the iso file had errors.

Comment: What errors did you see?

Comment: Download it again and don't forget t verify the hash sums of your downloaded file with the ones provided on the server.

Comment: Thank you for these responses - how do I see the size of the file on the server?

Comment: Scroll down on the page you used to see the file sizes. 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 for the desktop is listed as 1.4G. I suggest attempting to use the torrent file available on the same page as I've heard it's a bit more reliable [ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent]

Comment: If system requires 32 bit, you probably need Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Full Ubuntu uses Unity which requires a good GPU or better graphics support. And system so old as to need 32 bit will not have GPU strong enough for Unity. If newer system with 2GB of RAM or more then use 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?   See
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM   Check the number
   against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2. If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
3. Did you select the media check before trying to install? 
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4. Did you ever do a "memory check" (perhaps another live-media menu
   choice) on your PC? Doing the above can save you a lot of time
   struggling with a bad install media or hardware problems.